# $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\lambda x +\epsilon x(t-a)$ series solution via Laplace method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, perturbation-theory

Consider the following equation
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\lambda x +\epsilon x(t-a), \quad x(0)=1,\quad |\epsilon|\ll1$$
where $a$ and $\lambda$ are positive constants and $x(t-a)$ means the function $x(t)$ evaluated at $t-a$.
The task is to obtain a solution as a series in powers of $\epsilon$. The book suggests to show that $x(t)=e^{-\lambda t} w(t)$ satisfies
$$\frac{dw}{dt}=\delta w(t-a)\quad w(0)=1,\quad \delta=\epsilon e^{\lambda a}$$
and show that the perturbation expansion is given by the following expression:
$$w(t)=1+t\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\delta^n}{n!}\left(t-na\right)^{n-1}$$
hence
$$x(t)=e^{-\lambda t}\left(1+t\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\delta^n}{n!}\left(t-na\right)^{n-1}\right)$$
Since the method given in the solution is basically verification by substitution and proof by induction, I have been looking for a more systematic approach.
The presence of time delay in RHS suggests that Laplace transform method could be appropriate here. So I proceed as follows.
Apply Laplace transform to both sides of the original equation observing the initial conditions:
$$x(t)\fallingdotseq X(s)$$
$$sX(s)-x(0)=-\lambda X(s) +\epsilon e^{-sa}X(s)$$
Solve for $X(s)$:
$$X(s)=\frac{x(0)}{s+\lambda-\epsilon e^{-sa}}=\frac{1}{s+\lambda-\epsilon e^{-sa}}$$
Expand in powers of $\epsilon$:
$$X(s)=\frac{1}{s+\lambda}\left(\frac{1}{1-\epsilon\frac{e^{-sa}}{s+\lambda}}\right)=\frac{1}{s+\lambda}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon^n e^{-nas}}{(s+\lambda)^n}\right)=\frac{1}{s+\lambda}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon^n e^{-nas}}{(s+\lambda)^{n+1}}$$
Taking inverse transforms
$$\frac{1}{s+\lambda} \risingdotseq e^{-\lambda t}$$
$$\frac{e^{-nas}}{(s+\lambda)^{n+1}} \risingdotseq \frac{(t-na)^n e^{-\lambda(t-na)}}{n!}$$
But then I lose the factor of $t$ before the sum as compared to the book solution. Where am I making the slip?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the \fallingdotseq $\fallingdotseq$ for? I've never seen this notation.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva For noting it is an inverse transform equality, if I'm not reading wrongly.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff : I understand that on one side you have a function and on the other its Laplace Transform, but I wanted to know the precise meaning of the symbol.

Comment: I was just telling anon, sometimes people choose a simbol to denote something. Such as $e^{ta} \sqsubseteq \frac{1}{s-a}$

Comment: I realised that this is a possibly outdated symbol specific to old Russian textbooks for example [this one](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Ordinary_differential_equations.html?id=dzPvAAAAMAAJ). Could not find any I am aware of available in preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a slightly different approach, but here is how I would tackle this.

Let $D=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$, then we can rewrite your equation as
$$
(D+\lambda-\epsilon e^{-aD})x=0\tag{1}
$$
To invert the operator, consider the expansion:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\lambda+x-\epsilon e^{-ax}}
&=\frac{1}{\lambda+x}\frac{1}{1-\epsilon\frac{e^{-ax}}{\lambda+x}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda+x}+\epsilon\frac{e^{-ax}}{(\lambda+x)^2}+\epsilon^2\frac{e^{-2ax}}{(\lambda+x)^3}+\epsilon^3\frac{e^{-3ax}}{(\lambda+x)^4}+\dots\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Using integrating factors we get that
$$
(\lambda+D)^{-1}f=e^{-\lambda t}\int e^{\lambda t}f\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3}
$$
which leads us to
$$
(\lambda+D)^{-k-1}0=e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{j=0}^kc_j\frac{t^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}\tag{4}
$$
and therefore the coefficient of $\epsilon^k$ would be
$$
e^{-kaD}(\lambda+D)^{-k-1}0=e^{-\lambda (t-ka)}\sum_{j=0}^kc_j\frac{(t-ka)^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}\tag{5}
$$

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a close look. Surprisingly, your approach links to my [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151360/leftd2-fracz2a2-rightu-fraczagx-operator-solution) here