# Inverse Laplace transform computation

Tags: laplace-transform

> Calculate the inverse Laplace transform
> $$\mathcal{L^{-1}} \left\{ s\log \frac{s^2 + a^2}{s^2 - a^2}\right\},$$
> where $a\in\mathbb{C}$ is a constant.

I know that is boring but I would really appreciate some help.

Thank's in advance!

Comment: That $s$ at the front suggests something by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would proceed step by step as follows (using $\risingdotseq$ for the correspondence of the original and image):

$$f\left(x\right)\risingdotseq F=s\log\frac{s^{2}+a^{2}}{s^{2}-a^{2}}$$
$$\int_{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt\risingdotseq\frac{F}{s}=\log\frac{s^{2}+a^{2}}{s^{2}-a^{2}}$$
$$-x\int_{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt\risingdotseq \frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{F}{s}\right)=\frac{2s}{s^{2}+a^{2}}-\frac{2s}{s^{2}-a^{2}}$$
$$-x\int_{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt\risingdotseq\frac{2s}{s^{2}+a^{2}}-\frac{2s}{s^{2}-a^{2}}$$
inverting the RHS:

$$-x\int_{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt=2\cos ax-2\cosh ax \qquad (*)$$
**EDIT** (thanks to the comment by Fabian): differentiate once with respect to $x$ 
$$-\int_{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt-xf\left(x\right)=-2a\sin ax-2a\sinh2x$$
Now multiply by $x$ and subtract from (*):
$$x^2f(x)=2(ax\sin{ax}+ax\sinh{ax}+\cos{ax}-\cosh{ax})$$
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{x^2}(ax\sin{ax}+ax\sinh{ax}+\cos{ax}-\cosh{ax})$$

Comment: Funny sign `$\risingdotseq$'. Never saw this before. Does it have a conventional meaning?

Comment: I have already caused confusion in [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151336/fracdxdt-lambda-x-epsilon-xt-a-series-solution-via-laplace-method) here. Unfortunately, the textbooks I saw it in are so old that I am unable to find any of them available in preview online

Comment: By the way, I get a bit confused at the second displayed line after inverting the RHS. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: sorry, i should have made a note: it's differentiating wrt $x$

Comment: why you differentiate twice? How about subtracting $x$ times the first derivative from the original equation?

Comment: yes, you are right. i was taken off the tangent here

Comment: @Valentin: Thank you for your reply! I think we can write $-\int_{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt=\frac{1}{x}(2\cos ax-2\cosh ax)$ and then getting the derivative on both sides we find $f$.